# What happens to a pointer to another pointer when the first one is freed?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pointer-to-pointer

I have made a simulation of a stack using malloc to create an array of MAX elements and assign it to a pointer. I then made a second pointer pointing to the first one, to be able to navigate back and forth, executing pushes and pops.

```
int * stack= (int *) malloc(MAX * sizeof(*stack));
int * stack_ptr = stack;
```

In the end, I delete the pointer containing the array, using

```
free (stack);
```

After I delete the array (**stack**), **stack_ptr** is pointing to an address with no contents, right?

Can this cause a memory leak or any kind of problem, even if the program terminates exactly after?

Comment: It is *not* a pointer to another pointer, but a **copy** of the pointer obtained from malloc. Only one block of memory exists and you can use any copy of its pointer. It is the *value* you pass to `free` which matters, not which variable it is stored in. After that you must not dereference the pointer, no matter what variable it is stored in.

Comment: Google "dangling pointer" - don't worry - it's a genuine computing term and safe for work ;-)

Comment: `free (stack_ptr)` will also free the block. And just as you do not use stack_ptr to access the heap after freeing of the block it references, any other pointer referencing this block, must not access the freed block.

Comment: An example of **a pointer to another pointer** would be `int ** stack_ptr = &stack;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After I delete the array (stack), stack_ptr is pointing to an address with no contents, right?

After `free(stack);`, attempting to perform `*stack_pt` is *undefined behavior* (UB).  The contents pointed to `stack_pt`  may be good, bad or ugly or simply cause code to crash.  It is UB to attempt to find out.

> Can this cause a memory leak or any kind of problem, even if the program terminates exactly after?

Having a unchanged copy of the former valid pointer in `stack_pt` in itself in not a leak nor UB.  Just don't use `stack_pt`.

---

Often after freeing, it is good practice to `NULL` the pointer(s).

```
int * stack= (int *) malloc(MAX * sizeof(*stack));
int * stack_ptr = stack;
...
free (stack);
stack = NULL;
stack_ptr = NULL;
```

---

Aside: Recommend to allocate to the size of the referenced object, not the type and forego the unneeded cast.

```
// int * stack= (int *) malloc(MAX * sizeof(*stack));
int *stack =  malloc(sizeof *stack * MAX);
```

Answer (score 1):

No memory leak because you did a copy of pointer. So the pointer `stack_ptr` is pointing to not-allocate space.

If you want to read the content pointed by `stack_ptr` after your code it will cause a segmentation fault because you freed the space allocated by your malloc.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

You may or may not segfault if you try to dereference it, but it is dangling.  There is no memory leak though. stack_ptr is still on the stack, and will be popped off when the function returns, like normal stack variables.  You are freeing the memory that it points to.

Answer (score 1):

It is not pointer to pointer only both have the same value. Nothing will happpen to the second one. It will still have the same value, but this time it will reference not allocated memory.

this is pointer to pointer (ptr2):

```
int *ptr1;
int **ptr2 = &ptr1
```